# I added a user named Abc09$FtpU88F on a Centos 7 VM. But /etc/passwd is showing username Abc09 only. What did it do?

Tags: linux, centos-7

Environment: CentOS 7

Problem:

I used the useradd command:
useradd Abc09$FtpU88F

And when I checked using "cat /etc/passwd", it is showing me only part before $ sign in the passwd list.

How is $ sign used in useradd command? and how did it affect my user/server? If it is a problem, can it be fixed?

Comment: [`$` should not appear in any username](https://serverfault.com/a/578264).

Answer (score 2):

`$FtpU88F` is interpreted as an environment variable name expansion by the shell.
Since there is no such variable called FtpU88F (I presume) this is simply expanded into an empty string.
So you just ran the command `useradd Abc09`

It is a really bad idea to put special characters like a $ sign into a username.
Can potentially cause a lot of problems which other software that also mis-interpret the $ sign as the start of a environment variable.